# How to find and replace this string with Eclipse?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have some line of Java code like this:

```
Ball b = new Ball(Util.toPx(X*mR), y);
```

and I would like to replace this line with this

```
Ball b = new Ball(X*mR, y);
```

where X is a double number like 1.25, 1.765 etc.

How to obtain this with Eclipse search-replace feature?

Comment: Umm... what? This question doesn't make much sense. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Is this question about string manipulation in Java or about how to use a search-replace feature in Eclipse?

Comment: I edited the question sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: I don't understand your question. Even if I did, I'm sure it has nothing to do with Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about eclipse, but on sublime text 2 you can obtain it with the search feature with regex enabled. The regex would be something like:

```
Util\.toPx\((.*?)\)
```

And if you want to replace this String for something else you could do:

```
toPx($1)
```

It would replace the previous string to

```
toPx(X*mR)
```

If you have more groups between parentheses, you can use them on the replace expression with $1, $2, etc.